# Using def/val/var and how to define the null element in a linked list

Tags: scala

I want to implement some kind of a simple linked list.

I defined an abstract No, with a field next, its type is Node.
Then I have a bunch of other specific Node, inheriting the abstract node.

I write like this:

```
abstract class Node {
  def next: Node   
}

case class SpecificNode(nxt: Node) extends Node {
  val next = nxt
}

object NullNode extends Node{
  val next = new Exception("no more node")
}
```

However, I find that I need to change the field next later, in the SpecificNode, 
so I make

```
case class SpecificNode(nxt: Node) extends Node {
  var next = nxt
}
```

However, I can not assign to the `next` field of an instance of some specific node ,e.g `sn.next = ...`, because the compiler complains `next_` is not a member of Node.

Then I changed to use `var` in the abstract class Node for the `next` field.

But when I new a NullNode, exception will be thrown (since I defined so..)

So how should I use the `var`, `def`, `val` here? 
How should I define the NullNode, which is to signify no more node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to explicitly define getter/setter in your interface. In our case (without changing structure and idea):

```
trait Node {
    def next: Node
    def next_=(node: Node)
}

// `var next: Node` generates implementations for `def next: Node` and `def next_=(node: Node)`
case class SpecificNode(var next: Node) extends Node

object NullNode extends Node {
    def next = throw new Exception("no more node")
    def next_=(node: Node) { throw new Exception("can't change next on null node") }
}

val n1 = SpecificNode(NullNode)
val n2 = SpecificNode(SpecificNode(NullNode))
val n3: Node = SpecificNode(n1)

// some function to test our structure:
def length(n: Node, prev: Int = 0): Int = if (n == NullNode) prev else length(n.next, prev + 1)

println(length(n3))
n3.next = n2
println(length(n3))
```

Side note: this is mutable linked list, I suggest you to check how immutable list implemented in standard scala library

Comment: Thanks Sergey! I tried to do the setter, but didn't even notice that `next_=` rather than any space `next_ =`. Yeah, this is mutable, I just started to use scala, and want to do some fast prototype, was afraid that immutable implementation of linked lis in standard library could involve any advanced features that I may not need to know right now... this is bad move, I know. But I will try to make it. Thanks fr the advice!